# How to change Meta Robots for a page?

Tags: meta-tags

I want to change meta robots for a particular page. By default I find every meta robots value as `index/follow` but, I want to change meta robots for few pages as `noindex/follow`.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Tell me gays one thing if i want to change meta robots to Noindex,follow for every products in a website so is there any way to change it ones ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144400)

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to do this on certain CMS-pages you can easily do this by inserting the following into your XML layout update of those pages:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: And the same can be accomplished by using the correct layout update handle in the local.xml layout file.

Comment: This should also work for products and categories as well.